# how to ignore a folder with gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to ignore a folder within a gulp task, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here are the different tests I have done: all without success: the files are copied into the destination folder.

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            //sources  
            './src/**/*',
            // first test
            '!src/*views/*',
            // second test
            '!src/**views/'
        ])

        .pipe(cleanDest('./dev/'))
        //destination
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/'));
});
```

Has anyone of you ever encountered the problem and managed to work around it / solve it?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: did you try '!./src/views/**/*' ?

Comment: Hello @Dirk : Yes! it copies the folder, without the files, but the folder is still there and I have to delete it by hand, that's too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are .js files the below works for me:

```
return gulp.src(['./src/!(*views)/*.js'])
```

Comment: thank you @Mark . Inside the views folder, there are php files. I tested your syntax but nothing does: the folder is copied and the files are copied as well.

Comment: Hmm, works for me..  Try return gulp.src(['./src/!(views)/*.php']) and nothing else in gulp.src

Answer (score 0):

this will ignore the folder views.

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./src/**/*', '!src/**/views'])

    .pipe(cleanDest('./dev/'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/'));
});
```